# Jquery:how to get values of a class which belongs to two different parent classes?

Tags: jquery

I need to get values of a specific class which two different parent classes - has-file and no-file. And no-file parent class should have style "display:block". Here is my sample code snippet -

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:block;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="has-file">
            <span class="file-name">abc.jpg</span>
        </div>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:none;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="has-file">
            <span class="file-name">def.png</span>
        </div>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:none;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="no-file" style="display:block;">
            <span class="file-name">No file selected</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
```

I want the output to be -

```
No file selected
abc.jpg
def.png
No file selected
```

Comment: mmm can you be more clear on what you need?

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? You want a string with values separated by carriage returns?

Comment: the output is that http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/BfjRp/1/

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x5Nzx/1/)

**JQUERY**

```
$("table tr").each(function (i, v) {
    $("#container").append($(v).find("span.file-name:eq(0)").text() + "<br>");
});
```

this way, for each table row you will get the first span with class `file-name`, ignoring the second one (if exists).

note that I'm assuming that the div containing the file name (abc.jpg) comes always before the `No file selected` div, if it is present.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to produce your specified output as a string with the values separated by newline characters:

```
var values = $(".no-file").filter(function() {
                 return $(this).css("display") === "block";
             }).add(".has-file")
             .children(".file-name")
             .map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
             }).get().join("\n");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h3P8U/

> *And no-file parent class should have style "display:block"*

Here's another way that doesn't explictly test for the `display:block` but does test visibility:

```
var values = $(".no-file,.has-file").filter(":visible")
             .children(".file-name")
             .map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
             }).get().join("\n");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h3P8U/1/

Either way if you wanted the values as an array rather than a newline-joined string just omit the `.join()` call...

Comment: Thanks for both the replies. Both will work individually. But I have a variable which holds this whole table html content. Using that variable I need to filter and get the file names. How to approach that ?

Comment: Are you saying the html shown in your question isn't actually part of the page, but is a string in a JS variable? If so you can say `$(yourVarHere).filter(".no-file").filter(...etc...`